# How to auto start a java script fuction ?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I got a java script function and I want it to auto start but it wont.I've try the on load command and other stuff but it wont work here is the code in html .I just have to type something here who knows what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getlocation()">
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script>
getlocation()
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  var lat=position.coords.latitude
  var lon=position.coords.longitude;
  var latlon_url="http://example.com/latlon.php?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon;
  window.location=latlon_url;
  }

function showError(error)
  {
  switch(error.code) 
    {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: move `getlocation()` all the way down before closing script tag and change it to `getLocation()`

Comment: Call a function, after defining it

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work :_(

Comment: Your calling function name and defined function is no similar look-> `getlocation();`   and you define `function getLocation(){ }` with capital `L`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note here `getlocation()` and `getLocation()` will be different

move `getlocation()` all the way down before closing script tag and change it to `getLocation()` or change body tag to `<body onload="getLocation()">`

Comment: If you add that `onLoad` call along with the existing function call (as you suggested), this page will then call your function ***twice***

Comment: Yes, he/she can use either of them

Comment: Yes *either* is fine, as your edit suggests. But *both* were not fine.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive, so if you've called your function `getLocation` you should call it via `getLocation()` not all lowercase `getlocation()`.

Edit: It doesn't matter where you call getLocation(). It's hoisted to the top, no need to move it further down.

Answer (score 0):

you also seem to be depending on the DOM with this line

`var x=document.getElementById("demo")`

so I would wrap the whole thing on a window.onload function

delete the getlocation() at the top because it got incorrect causing for the Location,

then go a head and call that from inside the window.onload when the DOM loads like so

`window.onload = function () {
    getLocation();
}`

Answer (score 0):

**javascript is case sensitive**

`getLocation()` and `getlocation()` are different

try

```
<body onload="getLocation()">
```

or

```
<script>
getLocation();
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

getlocation() not equal getLocation()

JavaScript is Case Sensitive.

7th line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

These solutions will work:

```
    <body onload="script();">
```

or

```
     document.onload = function ...
```

or even

```
     window.onload = function ...
```